# Join through multiple tables in nHibernate via QueryOver

Tags: c#, join, nhibernate, aggregate-functions, multiple-tables

I have these tables: `components, devicehardwareprofiles, componenttemplates, cashrecyclercounters` on MsSql database

I need to fill this variables: `int capacity, loaded` by data from this query:

```
select sum(ct.capacity * cc.denomination) as capacity, sum(cc.loaded * cc.denomination) as loaded
from components c 
left outer join devicehardwareprofiles dhp 
    on dhp.deviceid = c.deviceid 
left outer join componenttemplates ct 
    on ct.hardwareprofileid = dhp.hardwareprofileid and ct.typecode = c.typecode and ct.position = 1 
left outer join cashrecyclercounters cc 
    on cc.componentid = c.componentid 
where c.deviceid = 72 and c.typecode = 155 and cc.currency = 810
```

How to convert this SQL to nHibernate QueryOver expression and get required data?

**Addition:** 
DTO and mappings are here: https://github.com/elscript/CashMaster

Typecode 155 stands for CashRecyclerHopper

I've already tried this one expression:

```
CashRecyclerHopper component = null;
DeviceHardwareProfile profile = null;
ComponentTemplate template = null;

var query = _cmSession.QueryOver(() => profile)
    .JoinQueryOver(x => x)
    .JoinAlias(a => a.HardwareProfileId, () => template, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .JoinAlias(b => b.DeviceId == component.ParentDevice.DeviceId, () => component, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.JoinAlias(c => c.HardwareProfileId == template.HardwareProfileId, () => template, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin);
```

But it gave me the exception:

> > Could not determine member from (b.DeviceId == value(CashMasterWeb.Controllers.OptimizationController+<>c__DisplayClass2).component.ParentDevice.DeviceId)
>
> Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not determine member from
>   (b.DeviceId ==
>   value(CashMasterWeb.Controllers.OptimizationController+<>c__DisplayClass2).component.ParentDevice.DeviceId)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 81:              ComponentTemplate template = null; Line 82:  Line 83:
>                 var query = _cmSession.QueryOver(() => profile) Line 84:                    .JoinQueryOver(x => x) Line 85:                     .JoinAlias(a => a.HardwareProfileId, () => template, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)

Comment: Are all of the associations mapped?

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker, not really. Is that a problem? If so, how do you suggest to map them for my purpose?

Comment: In order to `join` between tables with NHibernate, you need to map the associations. Mapping the foreign key column won't be enough.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker, could you point any reference or some example for me to be clear?

Comment: I'll try to find a good guide, but you want to look for "mapping associations with nhibernate" or "one-to-many with nhibernate"

Comment: On the line `.JoinAlias(b => b.DeviceId == component.ParentDevice.DeviceId, () => component, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)` you are using the alias `component` even before it is set. Is the correct?

Comment: @Suhas I guess, it's not correct.But the real problem is mapping, that are actually not full.